# linking openGL on BSD

Tags: opengl, nvidia, freebsd

I have a slightly strange problem with a program that uses openGL

If I try compiling on a FreeBSD machine with nvidia graphics using the link options `-pthread -lm -lX11 -lGL -lGLU`

I get the error:

```
//usr/local/lib/libGL.so: undefined reference to `_nv021glcore'
//usr/local/lib/libGL.so: undefined reference to `_nv013glcore
```

Open GL demos and things run fine on this same machine. If I try compiling the same program on another machine with the same version of FreeBSD but without nvidia boards present, it compiles, but if I try running the binary on the machine with the nvidia graphics, the program fails with

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  22
Current serial number in output stream:  2
```

OpenGL binary demos and things run fine on the same BSD machine, so there does not seem to be a problem with the GL setup and the same program causing this compiles and runs on linux, I'm at a loss as to what is causing this.

EDIT

most of these nvxxxcore functions seem to be exported from libnvidia-glcore.so.1
nm -D gives the exports :

```
00000000010abaa0 T _nv000glcore
00000000010aba90 T _nv001glcore
00000000010abac0 T _nv002glcore
00000000011322e0 T _nv003glcore
00000000010abae0 T _nv014glcore
00000000010d0200 T _nv015glcorea-tls.so which ma
00000000010bc9e0 T _nv016glcore
0000000001c27340 B _nv017glcore
0000000001578ac0 R _nv018glcore
0000000001584480 R _nv019glcore
0000000001c292c0 B _nv020glcore
0000000001c22080 B _nv022glcore
0000000000add970 T _nv023glcore
0000000001c27860 B _nv024glcore
0000000001c292a8 B _nv027glcore
0000000001c2a2a0 B _nv028glcore
0000000001c27178 B _nv029glcore
0000000001bf0248 D _nv035glcore
000000000119ba60 T _nv042glcore
```

Which does not include these missing links, but this still leaves me none the wiser of how to solve this.

EDIT

The exports in question are located in `libnvidia-tls.so` which makes this all the stranger, since this should be found since

```
readelf -d /usr/local/lib/libGL.so

Dynamic section at offset 0xf0e08 contains 26 entries:
Tag                Type                  Name/Value
0x0000000000000001 NEEDED               Shared library: [libnvidia-tls.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 NEEDED               Shared library: [libnvidia-glcore.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 NEEDED               Shared library: [libX11.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 NEEDED               Shared library: [libXext.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 NEEDED               Shared library: [libc.so.7]
0x000000000000000e SONAME               Library soname: [libGL.so.1]
0x0000000000000010 SYMBOLIC             0x0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually found the solution.
compilation can be done by passing `-u _nv021glcore -u _nv013glcore` which brings back the failed opcode. To solve this also need to startx with `-- +iglx` to enable indirect rendering which seems to be disabled by default these days as it seems to be considered legacy openGL

Comment: NVidia binary driver has its own libGL.so that replaces Mesa's one. That doesn't explain that strange symbol, though. You, probably, compiled binary on a system with NVidia's libGL, and then tried to run it on a system with Mesa.